# confusion with overriding ggplot data in a plot layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following is a short code to generate a barplot with an added layer of line plot. I have added comments indicating what works and what doesn't. While my problem is solved, I can't understand why I had a problem or how it got solved. If you can explain or suggest the right way to do it, that would be nice.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    factors <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "B", "A", "C", "B", "D", "D")
    data <- data.frame(n=1:10, a= runif(10, 1, 5), b=runif(10, 1, 5),c=runif(10, 1, 5))
    gg_data <- melt(data, id.vars="n", variable.name="var")
    gg_data$alp <- rep(factors, 3)
    gg_data1 <- melt(data.frame(n=1:10, a= runif(10, 2, 3), b=runif(10, 4, 5),c=runif(10, 3, 4)), id.vars="n", variable.name="var")

    #this does not work
    ggplot(data= gg_data, aes(x=n, y=value, fill=alp))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ facet_grid( var ~ ., scale="free_y")+geom_line(data= gg_data1, aes(x= n, y=value))

    #this gives a weird output
    gg_data1$alp <- rep(factors, 3)
    ggplot(data= gg_data, aes(x=n, y=value, fill=alp))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ facet_grid( var ~ ., scale="free_y")+geom_line(data= gg_data1, aes(x= n, y=value))

    #this works the way I want it to, don't know why.
    gg_data1$alp <- "A"
    ggplot(data= gg_data, aes(x=n, y=value, fill=alp))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+ facet_grid( var ~ ., scale="free_y")+geom_line(data= gg_data1, aes(x= n, y=value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically your plots are combining information from the two datasets to try to get a new plot. Since you have listed that `fill = alp`, then `ggplot` is trying to apply this information to all of your plots.

The easiest way to see this is consider this new `data.frame`:

```
gg1 <- gg_data1
names(gg1) <- c("n1", "var1", "value1")
gg_combine <- cbind(gg_data, gg1)
```

To reproduce your 2nd graph it is equivalent to:

```
ggplot(data=gg_combine, aes(x=n, y=value, fill=alp))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+ 
  geom_line(aes(x=n1, y=value1, colour=alp)) + 
  facet_grid( var ~ ., scale="free_y")
```

Basically what it is saying is I want to group everything by "alp" and plot them together by those groups, which is why you get those lines; with the addition of `colour=alp` then it becomes clear why the lines look that way.

[image]

With your last plot. What you've done is only group the bar plots with `alp`, but with the lines we want to ignore this grouping. This is equivalent to:

```
ggplot(data=gg_combine, aes(x=n, y=value))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill=alp), stat="identity")+ 
  geom_line(aes(x=n1, y=value1)) +
  facet_grid( var ~ ., scale="free_y")
```

[image]

Hope this helps.